# Free panning/scrolling on LibreOffice Draw

Tags: autohotkey, scrolling, libreoffice-draw

[LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) Draw allows me to scroll vertically or horizontally using my mouse as follows:

```
Scroll Wheel: Scroll vertically
Shift + Scroll Wheel: Scroll horizontally
```

My question is: Is there any way to have free scrolling/panning on it? By free scrolling/panning, I mean the ability to pan in any direction, e.g. diagonally. Many applications allow you to freely pan using methods like:

- A hand tool/ panning tool (click and drag, as in Photoshop or Illustrator)
- Middle click button on the mouse

If LibreOffice Draw doesn't support these scrolling methods natively, is it possible to simulate free-scrolling externally? Maybe using an **AutoHotkey** script that sends the scroll vertically or horizontally events when moving the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

There is, in fact, a panning tool. It is referred to as "Shift". It looks like an orange gloved hand hovering over a piece of paper: [image: orange hand hovering over a piece of paper]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi James / G-Man,
Do you know where I can find the button for this panning tool?  I cannot find that image on my version of Draw.
LibreOffice Version: 6.1.5.2 (x64)
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool to do this. It's called `Zoom & Pan`.

- go to `View -> Toolbars` and check `Standard` (not `Standard Viewing Mode`)
- find and click on Standard panel a button with magnifying glass [image] (The panel should be just below program menu)
- to use that tool in pan mode you need to hold `Shift` key

Tested in LibreOffice 6.2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

In 7.4.1.2 you can find the tool "Shift" in the Zoom toolbar.

[image]

But in my view pretty useless, it should be possible to activate this by a keyboard stroke or/and the mouse, or a combi of those, like in any other graphic application.